# Using selenium Python to automate to click the elements

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python. I want to automate to click the one of menu in the dropdown menu written as below. Let's say `"openExportDialog()"`  xpath is `//*[@id="globalMenuItems"]/li[1]/a`

Could anyone please shed some light?

```
<div id="nmapGlobalMenu" class="col-md-12 disable-user-select dropdown pr-0 show">
<button class="imgicon n-ui-icon n-ui-ic-operation myBasic_icon imgicon" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></button><div id="globalMenuItems" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" x-placement="bottom-end" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(803px, 33px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
</li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="openImportDialog()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu"> Import Node</span></a>
</li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="openExportDialog()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu"> Export Node</span></a>
    </li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="discoverNetwork()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu">Discover Network</span></a>
    </li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="openEmailSettingsView()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu"> Email Notification Settings</span></a>
    </li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="ICMPsettingsView()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu"> ICMP Health Check Settings</span></a>
    </li><li class=""><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="customTypeManagement()"><span class="vakata-contextmenu"> Node Type Management</span></a></li></div>
</div>
```

I hope the question is clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

once the dialog box is open, you can use this `//a[@onclick='openExportDialog()']` xpath to click on  `Export Node` option.

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@onclick='openExportDialog()']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

First click on the Button and then try to find the `a` tag. Like below:

```
driver find_element_by_id("globalMenuItems").click()
driver.find _element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Export Node')]").click()
```